# IOS - UIPageViewController go to previous page using page curl effect and show page number on each pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to use UIPageViewController,

I want to make app that swipes left and right with same view. I am using only one uitableview for infinite swiping of uipageviewcontroller.

[image: Table View]

This working fine using scroll effect but when I using page curl effect, It only allows to swipe right and didn't go to previous page.

Here is my code of PageViewController file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    _counter = 0;

    [self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"memoTable"]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark PageViewController delegate method

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Child controller counter before  = %d", _counter);

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageController class]])
        return nil;

    if(_counter < 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"memoTable"];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Child controller counter after  = %d", _counter);
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageController class]])
        return nil;
    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageView"];
}
```

So how can I achieve this using page curl effect and swipe left-right.

Thank you.

Comment: have you try first page curl to right and than left? are you able to get left swipe delegate ??

Comment: If I remove return nil; in counter < 1 than I get it working both side infinitely. But I want only right side infinite in page curl. @Dhanesh

Answer (score 0):

As you need is at single side infinite you need to check you `index` and if its 0 than `return nil` for that.

**check some methods of `PageViewController`:**

```
// Create the data model.
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        _pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy];

- (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard {
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (([self.pageData count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageData count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
    dataViewController.dataObject = self.pageData[index];
    return dataViewController;
}

- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController {
    // Return the index of the given data view controller.
    // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
    return [self.pageData indexOfObject:viewController.dataObject];
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageData count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

You have to manage one array also to recognise every thing `index | count`.

in above case `self.pageData` is my array to manage pages.
please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Can you add your array and what is DataViewController? @CodeChanger

Comment: `DataViewController` nothing but viewcontroller which i need to show on page view.

Comment: what kind of data is in your array? And how can I use this array ? @CodeChanger

Comment: its normal month data from Jan to Dec thats it you can use any kind of data here.

Comment: What is 'dataObject', Because I am getting error on that.

Comment: its simple string property of detailViewController `@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;` to show that string on label like this `self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject description];`

Comment: Ok Thanks. @CodeChanger

Comment: (TableViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard, This method not calling so I get index value as garbage values.

Comment: it will call from `- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` method. check above answer flow.